# iOS memory leak in thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting, nsthread

After running my thread for a while, Instruments shows that __NSDate has steadily incementing its # living value.

My conclusion is that this tread does not dealocate objects. This line, however, causes compilation error NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

How can I force this thread to retain all its objects or how shall I create a proper thread with working ARC.

```
- (void) start {
   NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                          selector:@selector(myThreadMainRoutine)
                                          object:nil];
   [myThread start];  // Actually create the thread
}

- (void)myThreadMainRoutine {

   // stuff inits here ...


   // Do thread work here.
   while (_live) {

      // do some stuff ...

      [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.05]];        
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05f];
   }

   // clean stuff here ...

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The autoreleased objects are probably the reason for the increasing memory usage,
but you cannot use `NSAutoreleasePool` with ARC. Replace

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// ...
[pool drain];
```

with

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // ...
}
```

*Update:* You actually need two autorelease pools in your case. First of all, the
[Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) states:

> If your application uses the managed memory model, creating an
>   autorelease pool should be the first thing you do in your thread entry
>   routine. Similarly, destroying this autorelease pool should be the
>   last thing you do in your thread. This pool ensures that autoreleased
>   objects are caught, although it does not release them until the thread
>   itself exits.

And the last sentence gives the clue why you need another autorelease pool: Otherwise
all autoreleased objects created in the long-running loop would only be released when 
the thread exits. So you have

```
- (void)myThreadMainRoutine {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // stuff inits here ...
        while (_live) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                // do some stuff ...
                [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.05]];        
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05f];
            }
        }
        // clean stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I put it inside while loop, what about the code before and after this, shall I have one autoreleasepool block for the whole function and second autoreleasepool inside my while loop?

Comment: @michael: My last comment was actually wrong, you need two pools. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)myThreadMainRoutine {
    @autoreleasepool {
       // stuff inits here ...

       // Do thread work here.
      while (_live) {
          // do some stuff ...
          [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.05]];        
          [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05f];
      }

      // clean stuff here ...

   }
}
```

Comment: But that did not clean NSDate objects during the loop, only after the method finishes, I had to put it inside while loop, is it ok?

Comment: you can have more than one autorelease pool, and using them where you want to release temp objects as soon as possible. Note that in a custom thread, you need at least one pool for the whole thread.